# Preferred Method of Creating Constants

Tags: ruby

I am quit new to Ruby and was practicing by making a MasterMind game. I have a class called `Color` as shown below.

```
module Colors
  LIST =
  {
      R: "Red",
      B: "Blue",
      G: "Green",
      Y: "Yellow",
      V: "Violet",
      P: "Purple",
      I: "Indigo",
      A: "Ash",
      O: "Orange"
    }
class Colors
  def initialize

  end


  def self.generate_colors(amount)
    # LIST.to_a.sample(amount)
    sample = []
    list = LIST.to_a
    amount.times{ sample << list[Random.rand(list.length-1)] }
    sample
  end

  def self.get_color(key)
    LIST[key]
  end

  def self.get_color_keys (colors)
    keys_array = []
    colors.each{|key, color| keys_array << key.to_s;}
    return keys_array
  end

  def self.get_color_values(colors)
    values_array = []
    colors.each{|key, color| values_array << color}
    values_array
  end
end
end
```

My instructor says that the `LIST` Constants can easily be placed within the `Colors` class so that I just call a method, say,  `get_colors`, to return for me the color list.

Since I am new to Ruby I will like to know what the normal Ruby convention is, which method do you think is a better approach.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much... But I will just like to know if there is a convention I should be using

Comment: *"the LIST Constants"* - plural? There's only one constant: `LIST`. The color keys are symbols.

Comment: What's the purpose of your `Color::Colors` class? Do you really need all these methods or are you implementing them "just in case"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your class has mostly `class` methods, it seems to act like a module. Your code can be simplified to below.  Unless `class` has some state (some instance variables), there will not be need to instantiate it.

```
module Colors
    COLORS = {
      R: "Red",
      B: "Blue",
      G: "Green",
      Y: "Yellow",
      V: "Violet",
      P: "Purple",
      I: "Indigo",
      A: "Ash",
      O: "Orange"
    }

    def self.pick_colors(count)
        sampled_keys = []
        count.times { sampled_keys << COLORS.keys.sample }
        sampled_keys
    end
end

p c = Colors.pick_colors(2)
#=> [:R, :A]

p Colors::COLORS[c[0]]
#=> ["Red"]

p Colors::COLORS
#=> {:R=>"Red", :B=>"Blue", :G=>"Green", :Y=>"Yellow", :V=>"Violet", :P=>"Purple", :I=>"Ind
```

As far as definition of constants go, they are better off defined in the place they most logically belong - it can be a `Module` or a `Class`, depending on who is introducing those constants to the user (programmer)

Comment: wow, really,  this is nice, obviously now the Colors::Colors class is  no longer needed, thank you, I understand your method

Comment: Note that `sample(n)` returns *n* unique elements, that's not equivalent to the OP's code.

Comment: @Stefan Agreed.  There was commented `sample` in OP's code, so I was not sure what OP wanted

Comment: @WandMaker well, you can use `COLORS.keys.sample` to get a single random element and repeat that *n* times.